# How to find out memory leaks in react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've build a learning management system app in react native android.I'm using `AsyncStorage` for simple state management and not used redux at all.The issue I'm facing now is if I'm going to use the app continuously by performing different actions then the app become very slow.I think it is memory leak because when I kill the app from background and open it again it is working without any delay.So I don't know how to avoid this memory leak.I've tried many solutions

1. Removed all `console.log` from app
2. Changed all inline styles
3. Used `ComponentDidMount` instead of `ComponentWillMount`.
4. Tried prefetching of data.

But I don't know how remove data from heap memory.Is the data is getting stored within `heap`on each navigation?So this will makes the app very slow in performance. I don't know whether I'm right.Excuse me if there is any mistake in my concept.There is no time to change the state management to `redux` now.Anybody please help me to find a solution , it will be a great help.Thank you!

Comment: Have you removed all your timers and eventlisteners in `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: You can use either Android Studio Profiler tools on android and Debug navigator on iOS, to hunt for memory leaks.

Comment: @NilsKähler yes I am unmounting eventlisteners .So in android studio will it show where memory leak is occuring and how?

Comment: If you go to profiler, then you will see a graph of your memory, then you can see if the momory increases every time you route to a new page or execute an action.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, few methods that helped were:

**Using transform-remove-console:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console

add this to your babel production plugins and install it. It will hide all the console logs in the app in production.

**Adding a mounted state**

> Specifically, calling setState() in an unmounted component means that
>   your app is still holding a reference to the component after the
>   component has been unmounted - which often indicates a memory leak!

https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class App extends Component {

  _isMounted = false;

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    // ... do your stuff here
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // tells the component that component is now unmounted
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  getUsersFromApi(){
    if(this._isMounted){
      // ... tasks
    }
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: I've tried both the methods.But still the response is same

Answer (score 6):

I too had the same issue, because of calling `setState` on an unmounted component,

So, I usually have this template for any class-based component that has a state:

I forgot about `setState()`, and use `setComponentState` declared down:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // other fields...

    };
    this.isUnmounted =  true,
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.isUnmounted =  false;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      this.isUnmounted = true;
  }

  setComponentState = (values) => {
    if (!this.isUnmounted) this.setState(values);
  };
}
```

Comment: can you show this for the functional component too? How to use useState and its value by this approach